# How to get all the element from JDBC query

Tags: java, sql, orm, jpa

HI,

I have query like this

```
final Query contractQuery = cgnDao.getEntityManager().
            createNativeQuery("SELECT k.phrase, ak.type FROM key k INNER JOIN adkey ak USING (key_id) WHERE pck.pub_id =" + pid +" AND pck.c_id =" + campId );
```

How can i get each and every element from the query?

Where phrase is an String and type is enum

in Java

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See both [this link on the JBoss JPA docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/query_native.html) and [this link on java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.persistence/QuerygetResultList.htm).

In short, you have a Query on which you can call getResultList(), which returns a List you can iterate over. Have a look at the [JPA javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/persistence/package-summary.html).

Also, I'd recommend using PreparedStatements, something like

```
String sqlQuery = "select * from tbl_spaceship where owner = ?";
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, SpaceShip.class);
q.setParameter( 1, "Han" );
q.getResultList();
```

The advantage is that the JPA provider will take care of escaping the input values. Not necessary at this particular use-case but good habits never hurt.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use String concatenation but **positional parameters** (*only positional parameter binding may be portably used for native queries*). Second, for a native query returning scalar values, the result would be a `List` of `Oject[]`. So the result might look like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT k.phrase, ak.type " + 
             "FROM key k INNER JOIN adkey ak USING (key_id) " +
             "WHERE pck.pub_id = ?1 AND pck.c_id = ?2";
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
q.setParameter(1, pubId);
q.setParameter(2, cId);
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
```

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 3.6.3 "Named Parameters"
  - Section 3.6.6 "SQL Queries"
  - Section 4.6.4 "Input Parameters"

Answer (score 0):

You can use value of method to gets enum instances from result set

```
enum A {}
A.valueOf()
```